# Unique Pattern in Passport Authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, passport.js

This is my first time implementing authentication.  I came across this in some of the meanjs example projects:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        scope: ['email']
      })(req, res, next);
    });
```

My main source of confusion is the (req, res, next) invocation - I haven't seen it before like that.  what exactly is going on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The function app.get requires two inputs: a path and a callback function.
**2.** The callback function has three inputs: req, res, next.
**3.** The callback function, inside its body calls a function generator (passport.authenticate) that returns a function. 
**4.** This function generator or function factory itself takes two inputs: 'facebook' and object with scope property.
**5.** Finally the function returned from authenticate is itself called using original req, res and next parameters.